# how to run an installation file

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, antivirus, multiarch

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 at a further PC and I am trying to install ESET antivirus software. The only information I could get from the firm is a file `eset_nod32av_64bit_cs.linux`, a note that I should make it executable and run it and system requirements according to https://help.eset.com/eav_linux/4/en-US/ud_install.html?ud_ena_intro_requirements.html, mainly:

- kernel 2.6.x and later

  - GNU C Library 2.3 or newer
  - GTK+ 2.6 or newer
  - LSB 3.1 compatibility recommended

I have set the 'executable' permission to that file, executed it as the root and I have got the message, the translation of it is:

> Please install the following files or packages: libc6:i386, /lib/ld-linux.so.2.

I have not found anything like it in the Ubuntu software center. How should I install them? Thanks!

(A remark for a moderator:[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218856/i-accidentally-created-two-accounts-how-do-i-merge-them))

Comment: [Installation error on Debian 10.2 x64](https://forum.eset.com/topic/22112-installation-error-on-debian-102-x64/) (ignore the first answer)

Comment: Should I try 'sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get install libc6-i386' at the new PC?

Comment: @ steeldriver: Chromium is crashing every several seconds at the PC from which I am sending this my second comment. I cannot use that PC to edit this question, I need that further PC, correctly protected.

Answer (score 0):

At least a part of the question - how to get rid of the message about the need to install libc6: i386 - has a solution that the [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) brought me to. 
He led me at the [ESET support page](https://support.eset.com/en/kb5827-installation-error-eset-nod32-for-linux-needs-the-following-packages-to-install-libc6-i386-libld-linuxso2-with-eset-nod32-antivirus-4-for-linux-desktop). I see that my 'Recommended updates (xenial-updates)' are checked, similarly as 'Recommended updates(trusty-updates)' for another Linux distribution in that manual and I hope the alerts

```
me@furtherPC:~$ software-properties-gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gdk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
me@furtherPC:~$
```

don't matter. Software Updater tells that my Ubuntu 16.04 is up to date.
The recommended commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

worked without warning. After the furtherPC restart

```
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get install libc6-i386
[sudo] password for as_a_root: 
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$
```

has not worked but

```
 
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

has downloaded and installed 10.4 MB files. Now running that installation file

```
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me/pathESET$ ./eset_nod32av_64bit_cs.linux
No protocol specified
(eset_nod32av_64bit_cs.linux:5531): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me/pathESET$
```

will not raise the message that libc6: i386 is needed, however it reports  further errors. Perhaps I understand correctly that

```
me@furtherPC:~/pathESET$ dpkg-query -W libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-bin    3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
me@furtherPC:~/pathESET$
```

means that the furtherPC has the required GTK + 2.6 or newer installed. I have also asked ESET support and will tell the result here.

Comment: There is a mess with my identity. I (= user:165175) have written and am responsible for both this question and the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Continuation from the answer 1.:

From the response from ESET support, it was inferred that it was needed

```
as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

. I tried the result and the installer went to run it

```
 as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me$ echo $DISPLAY
 :0.0
 as_a_root@furtherPC:/home/me/pathESET$ ./eset_nod32av_64bit_cs.linux
```

However, the ESET window display problems, that were one of the reasons for the reinstallation, persist. 7.4.2020, ESET shows all the necessary information.